# Will I gain by investing in an Nvidia graphics card to process family photos?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I want to purchase a Lenovo laptop. Some laptops come with Intel graphics (usually 4400) while others Nvidia (usually GeForce GT820M). If my usage is to view movies and process family photos, will investing in Nvidia give benefit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point the difference between the Intel HD integrated graphics and the nVidia chips is minimal for the kinds of tasks you are considering.

nVidia is a better chip and will give you an advantage in the processing of extremely large graphics in a GPU acceleration aware application (Adobe Photoshop is the only one that I know of that will use a dedicated GPU), but in all honesty editing family photo's generally isn't going to need that added power. Perhaps if you are using RAW photo files from a dSLR at a very high resolution you may notice a difference.

As for HD film, as long as you use a hardware accelerated player (VLC, SplashPlayer) you'll not be able to tell the difference between the two chipsets. For example, my netbook has a tiny dual core AMD c50 CPU from about 4 years ago and that will play full spec 1080p encoded video stutter free.